# C# The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract

I'm trying to build a C# project of another guy.
In a lot of interfaces I get the error:

```
The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item
```

In the following Interface:

```
namespace Services.Email
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using.System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public interface IEmailService
    {
        abstract event EventHandler<SendCompletedEventArgs> SendSummaryCompleted;

        void SendNewsItem(DocumentNewsItem newsItem, string email);
        void SendSummaryAsync(Session session, Advisor advisor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider replacing the other guy.   There is no excuse to hand in code that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just remove `abstract`, it's not applicable to interfaces. Everything in an interface is already essentially "abstract". An abstract class is actually in many ways the same thing as a class with a required interface that is not implemented.

Comment: +1 - It's best to have either one or the other depending on the design of your application, never both!#

Comment: My point would be an abstract class isn't just like a regular class with an implicit interface to implement. In my coding, I choose abstract classes or interfaces depending on what the type is representing in a conceptual point of view. For example, if I want to ensure that some classes would be able to be JSON-serializable, I'd choose to implement a "IJsonSerializable" interface, while if I want that any derived class of some base one would be able to be JSON-serializable, I'd prefer to impement a "JsonSerializableObject" abstract class.

Comment: @Matias: What you're describing is the oft-touted rule that interfaces describe a *has-a* or *can-do* relationship, while classes describe an *is-a* relationship.

Comment: That fact defines why you would or wouldn't use an abstract class (the *has-a* serializer, vs. *is-a* serializer). I'm just saying that in implementation, the only practical difference between an abstract class, and a regular class which (though some non-existent notation) required a particular interface, is that the interface in an abstract class is not usable outside that base class. Which makes it "is".

Comment: I'm just adding info! I wasn't discussing this answer.

Comment: I understand, I was just discussing :) In practice I think there's a lot of gray area in the way people use interfaces in C#, e.g. to simulate multiple inheritance or as markers so they could represent either has-a or is-a in a particular usage.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664580%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

All interface members implicitly have public access. It is a compile-time error for interface member declarations to include any modifiers. In particular, interfaces members cannot be declared with the modifiers abstract, public, protected, internal, private, virtual, override, or static.

Solution: Remove "abstract" modifier

Comment: The link is no longer valid. I think here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are not allowed to contain modifiers like `abstract`,  `virtual`, `public`, `protected`, `private`, ...
Solution:
Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET and C#, member modifiers in interfaces aren't supported.

If you want such thing you'd be better switching them to abstract classes, but IMHO this isn't a good way of developing software (refactoring code without thinking what's the actual requirement).

Easy solution: just remove any modifier, leave type, identifier and parameters of any kind of interface member.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not valid.  Remove the abstract keyword and re-compile.